# Issuing Teradata SQL Assistant query via script

Tags: sql, scripting, db2, teradata

I use Teradata SQL Assistant to run SQL queries against a DB2 database accessed via an ODBC connection. This is an entirely interactive process whereby I first start the SQL Assistant app, then connect to the correct data source and finally write and execute my query.

What I would like to do is to be able to achieve the same result, i.e. get the result set from a query, but via some sort of script, which would connect to the the data source and run my query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Install the [IBM Data Server Client software appropriate for your version of DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878), then use the DB2 command line processor with the `-f` option, [as described in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F3-6-2-0-2&lang=en).